# GetAdaptersAddresses и выделение памяти

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Итак имеем функцию GetAdaptersAddresses, которая возвращает список сетевых интерфейсов в системе. Описание ф-ции:

```
ULONG WINAPI GetAdaptersAddresses(
  _In_    ULONG                 Family,
  _In_    ULONG                 Flags,
  _In_    PVOID                 Reserved,
  _Inout_ PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES AdapterAddresses,
  _Inout_ PULONG                SizePointer
);
```

**AdapterAddresses [in, out]**
A pointer to a buffer that contains a linked list of IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES structures on successful return.
**SizePointer [in, out]**
A pointer to a variable that specifies the size of the buffer pointed to by AdapterAddresses.

Согласно логике вещей, размер буфера должен быть кратен sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES), однако на практике получается не так. Код:

```
ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER;
ULONG buffLen = 0;
IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES* adapters = nullptr;

ULONG ret = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, flags, NULL, NULL, &buffLen);
```

buffLen  = 3128
sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES) = 376

3128 / 376 = 8,3...

Основной вопрос: почему размер буфера не кратен размеру входящего в него элемента и как правильно выделять память под буфер с помощью new[]?

Описание функции:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: А на какой Windows вы проверяете?

Comment: Вообще в этой статье, которую вы написали рекомендуют выделять по крайней 15 КБ памяти.

Comment: размер буфера тут не может быть кратен размеру входящего в него элемента, потому что тут используется дополнительная память на формирование списков адресов (PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS, PIP_ADAPTER_ANYCAST_ADDRESS и т.п).

Comment: @Unick, это плохой пример) правильнее при первом вызове GetAdaptersAddresses передать в качестве AdapterAddresses NULL и тогда функция вернет требуемый размер буфера в SizePointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут надо пояснить, что выдает `GetAdaptersAddresses`. Она выдает не массив структур `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`, а наполняет переданный буфер данными, формируя однонаправленный связнный список таких структур. Помимо структур `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`, в этом же буффере будут данные, на которые указывают поля этой структуры, например текст с именем адаптера и т.п. Для работы следует выделить просто массив байт:

```
::ULONG buffLen{};
auto const retl{::GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, flags, nullptr, nullptr, &buffLen)};
if(ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW != retl)
{
    // обработка ошибки...
}
auto const p_buf{::std::make_unique<::std::uint8_t[]>(buffLen)};
auto const p_first{reinterpter_cast<::PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES>(p_buf.get())};
auto const ret{GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, flags, nullptr, p_first, &buffLen)};
if(ERROR_SUCCESS != ret)
{
    // обработка ошибки...
}
for(auto p_info{p_first}; p_info; p_info = p_info->Next)
{
    // обходим...
}
```

Comment: Да, каждая структура из возвращаемого списка содержит в себе такие же списки в полях FirstUnicastAddress, FirstAnycastAddress ... и вообще не так проста. Кроме вашего варианта можно выделять память через винапишные HeapAlloc(...) или обычный malloc.